# Time-Independent Quantum Hamiltonians and Thermodynamic Equilibrium

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

Suppose we have a time-independent Hamiltonian operator $\hat{H}$ of some system. We know that we can express the canonical partition function of said system as $z = \text{Tr}(e^{\beta\hat{H}})$ for some inverse temperature $\beta$. Now from my understanding, a time-independent Hamiltonian does not necessarily imply that the system is in thermal equilibrium. So my question is, what are the conditions that put the system with a conserved Hamiltonian in/out of thermal equilibrium?

I ask because I am having a bit of hard time understanding this concept. If my question turns out to be a bit to vague I will try and elaborate a bit more as best I can but I am unsure about the details.